# Create and validate Express account from API in Stripe

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

When I add an Express account from the dashboard, it is created enabled, ready for testing, but when I want to create an account from the API, I can't activate it, what am I doing wrong? Thx!

```
new AccountService().Create(new AccountCreateOptions
{
    Email = email,
    Country = "US",
    Type = "express",
    BusinessType = "individual",
    Individual = new AccountIndividualOptions
    {
        Phone = phone,
        FirstName = name,
        LastName = name,
        Dob = new DobOptions
        {
            Day = 1,
            Month = 1,
            Year = 2000
        },
        SsnLast4 = ssnLast4, // "0000"
        Verification = new AccountIndividualVerificationOptions
        {
            Document = new AccountIndividualVerificationDocumentOptions
            {
                Back = CreateFile(formFile).Id, //success.png
                Front = CreateFile(formFile).Id //success.png
            }
        }
    },
    BusinessProfile = new AccountBusinessProfileOptions
    {
        ProductDescription = "A dummy description"
    },
    ExternalAccount = new AnyOf<string, AccountBankAccountOptions, AccountCardOptions>(new AccountBankAccountOptions
    {
        Country = "US",
        Currency = "usd",
        AccountHolderName = name,
        RoutingNumber = "110000000",
        AccountNumber = "000123456789",
        AccountHolderType = "individual"
    }),
    TosAcceptance = new AccountTosAcceptanceOptions
    {
        ServiceAgreement = "full"
    },
    Capabilities = new AccountCapabilitiesOptions
    {
        Transfers = new AccountCapabilitiesTransfersOptions
        {
            Requested = true
        },
    },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the Stripe account has to accept Stripe's terms of services before the account can be activated. The best option here is to have them go through Connect Onboarding after you collected all the information: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding

It says Custom accounts but it works for all types now and will just have your customer "claim" their account and associate it with an email address and a phone number and accept the ToS.